# If you called someone named "Shelly" "Shels" for short, would you spell it "Shels" or "Shells?"

Tags: abbreviations, names, proper-nouns, nicknames, diminutives

Or Kelly -- "Kels" or "Kells?"

Is there a rule for this?

If it's just a judgement call, I'm inclined to go with one "l" as both "Shells" and "Kells" have potentially confusing homonyms.

I'm talking about in fiction dialog, not real life...

> "I don't know," Shelly said.
>
> "I'm telling you, Shels [or Shells?]," Monica replied, "There's nothing to worry about."

Comment: Nicknames have no standardised spellings. You can spell them however you (or rather, however the bearer of the name) prefers to. “Hey Shelllz, what up?”

Comment: Keep in mind that **most** one-syllable words in English of the CVC pattern that end in /l/ are spelled with a double-L, not a single one, eg: *ball bell bill brill bull call cell chill cull dell dill doll drill droll
dull dwell fall fell fill frill full gall gill grill gull hall hell hill
hull jill kell kill knell knoll krill kvell lull mall mill mull null pall
pill poll pull rill roll scall schill scroll scull sell shall shell shill
shrill sill skell skill skull small smell spell spill stall still stroll
swell swill tall tell thrall thrill till trill troll trull wall well will*

Comment: My brother has one of those names.  He prefers two final constants, but recognizes that only person consistent one way or the other is himself.  His friends, parents, and sibling go back and forth in spelling between one and two final constants.

Comment: @tchrist: Against that, firstly one might reasonably choose ***Shels*** in OP's context to avoid confusion with the plural of an existing word. Secondly, nicknames like ***Del*** and ***Tel*** are almost always spelt like that, and I'm sure lots of people will sometimes add an ***-s*** to those and others like them.

Comment: Shel Silverstein is someone who uses a single-l spelling, a contraction of Sheldon, so if it's not already clear from the story, people might assume Shel is a male. (I would have assumed that Shelly was already a contraction of Michelle).

Answer (score 1):

As @Janus Bahs Jacquet wrote "nicknames have no standardised spellings." Thus I would suggest `Shel` not `Shels` for `Shelly`.

*Shells* remind one with certain oil companies which are growing unpopular and things that go off at very unpleasant times. Likewise *Shell*. In addition, *Shels* sounds and looks plural. As for Kelly we can't of course go for Kel or Kil! How about K ?

Comment: Lots of hypocoristics have an extra diminutive _-s_. It doesn't make the name sound plural, just familiar (other common ones include Wills, Jules, Becks [David Beckham], Mags, Babs, etc.). An extra diminutive _-y/-ie_ is sometimes added, too (Magsie, Banksy, etc.).